# Necessary to @synchronize access to variable when using blocks with NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I have a high level class which makes several connections (sequentially, not in parallel) by using other classes which in turn each use an NSURLConnection.

One of these auxiliary classes downloads an array of items which it passes to the high level class via a delegate protocol as an NSArray. The high level class has its own NSArray and adds the downloaded items to its array.

I have several classes in an inheritance hierarchy, each class being responsible for downloading or uploading different content, all controlled by the high level class which is implementing a protocol for each. However I think having several classes in this inheritance hierarchy is perhaps overkill and am looking at making things simpler, and was wondering if instead of having several objects I could reduce it down and get the difference in behavior by the high level class supplying them with a block to be executed on content download.

So for example, the high level class would supply code to parse and create the NSArray that is downloaded as a block.

In sketch pseudo form:

```
@interface highLevelClass : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *theArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) downloadingClass *theDownloader;
- (void) doDownload;
@end



@interface downloadingClass : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *connection;
- (void) downloadArrayWithBlock:(void(^)()) theBlock;
@end



- (void) doDownload {
    [theDownloader: downloadArrayWithBlock:^ {
       [self.theArray appendObject: someObject]; 
     }
}

downloading class would execute the block in its implementation of NSURLConnectionDelegate:connectionFinishedLoading.
```

Firstly I presume highlevelClass's theArray needs to be declared using __block?

But my main question is: do I need to do anything, and if so what and how, to protect theArray against possible simultaneous access?

The highLevelClass might delete an item from theArray in response to a timer event or user action. My code is not using any threads and everything within it can therefore be nonatomic and doesn't need protecting against simultaneous updating. However NSURLConnection internally spawns a new thread I believe, and therefore if theArray is within a block passed to downLoading class, is there any possibility for danger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to take any precautions with locks if you're not spawning any threads yourself. While it's true that NSURLConnection spawns its own threads to perform the async download, it also takes care to send all of its delegate messages on the thread that started the download. In your case, since you're starting all downloads on the main thread, you know that all your delegate messages will also be received on the main thread.

And, as for the `__block` specifier, you only need that if the block will change the *pointer* to that array, not the array that it points to.